# bcrypt issue using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have successfully encrypted the password and stored in my DB during registration. But when I am login, I am comparing the password and trying to login, during the login period my sql query is falling to read the password and I am getting **hash is not defined**. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
 router.post('/login', function(req,res) {
 var password = req.body.password;
 var user_name = req.body.user_name;
 var response = {};
bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
db.query('select user_id,email FROM user where password = ? AND user_name = ? OR email = ?',
[hash, req.body.user_name, req.body.user_name], function (error,rows) {
  if (error) {
    res.json(error)
} else {    
 response.msg = 'Login Success';
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: `hash` is not defined because you didn't specify it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/login', function(req,res) {
  var password = req.body.password;
  var user_name = req.body.user_name;
  var response = {};
  var hash = db.query('SELECT hash FROM user WHERE user_name = ?', [req.body.user_name]);

  bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
  db.query('select user_id,email FROM user where password = ? AND user_name = ? OR email = ?',
[hash, req.body.user_name, req.body.user_name], function (error,rows) {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error)
    } else {    
      response.msg = 'Login Success';
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: i just implemented your technique, but i got response undefined error

Comment: that's not the issue. I checked in my console. I am fetching the password, but my password is failing to compare the hash code

Comment: Do you have a link to your code, say on CodePen? I would like to inspect the full code.

Comment: The `hash` can't be `req.body.password` it needs to be the hashed password that was saved to the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159896/discussion-between-vipe-and-john-kennedy).

Comment: should i call it through function and compare it?